# Enumerating USB drives and usb hierarchy on Mac OS

Tags: macos, usb

What is the best way to discover what USB drives are connected, where they are mounted, and their unique details like Serial number, PID and which USB Hub port they are connected to? Something similar to what [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/) does for Windows but programmatically.

Comment: By the way, for Windows, you don't need USBlyzer, you can use the builtin and very powerful `WMIC` command

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Terminal and execute:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

It will show all connected USB devices, with detailed information.

Comment: If you want to get it programatically add the `-xml` flag for a plist of the results

Answer (score 5):

The Finder has an "about this mac" option under the Apple at the upper left. Ask for more info and follow the devices===> USB tree to find your answers. In a shell or another executing module, I have no idea how to retrieve this info.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the information I need, except I need to get it programmatically!

Comment: A shell script would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

USB Prober is the most useful tool. It can be found at /Developer/Applications/Utilities/USB Prober.

Comment: (USB Prober is part of the separate IOUSBFamily package under Developer Downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of I/O on Mac OS X, but I've heard of [I/O Kit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/), which may be a good starting point.